# how to build a schema with multiple type of items (services, parts, and insurance etc.)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to design schema for a project that involves two things.

1. providing services ( realted to vechicles)
2. Also sells insurance , spare parts and maybe other types also can be added later 

   For each type of item order processing might be different, so I need to know the item type before order processing.
   Also I need to know which type of item is in the cart so I can join to that table accordingly.

   I also have a `UsedCoupons` table which contains `item_id` and `coupon_id`. Here also I need to know the item type.
   same for `cartItems` and `orders`

So far I can think of two approaches, but I don't think they are correct. I will explain below.

1. There will be tables for each items `insurances` `spareParts` `services` etc.
 One more table to store types.

```
itemTypes
--------------------
id
type_name
```

now `usedCoupons`, `cartItems` and `orders` will contain a `item_type_id` along with `item_id`.
*But here, I won't be able to join tables. As they depend on `item _types`*
2. Putting `item_type_id` in just each items: `insurances`, `spareParts` `services` etc. ,
 and putting only `item_id` into `usedCoupons`, `cartItems`< and `orders` tables.
But in this case I have to make a parent for all services.

```
itemParent
---------------------
id
name
description
item_id
item_type_id
```

Now again joining is painful here too.
I will join the `cartItems` to `items`, but for details again look for it's type before joining to a particular table.
For both approaches, I don't think they are right. There might be some other solution, If someone could help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database) , I think I can go with below schema

```
Items
--------------------
item_id (primary key)
name
description
price
item_type_id ( here foreign key, primary key for item types)
//it contains all the shared attributes in each type of items

Services
-----------------------
service_id (primary key)
item_id (foreign key, primary for Items)
....other attributes

SpareParts
---------------------
spare_part_id (primary_key)
item_id (foreign key, primary for Items)
....other attributes


Insurances
-----------------------
insurance_id (primary_key)
item_id (foreign key, primary for Items)
....other attributes

//Finally have a ItemTypes tables

ItemsTypes
---------------------
item_type_id (primary key)
item_type ( varchar, name of the item type : service, insurance)
```

Now, `UsedCoupon` `CartItems` and `Orders` will have only `item_id`
*But still I need someone's attentions here, If someone could help I will appreciate it.*